# Is the word "entrepreneurship" used correctly here?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, idiomatic-language

I'm doing some exercises with open clauses and there's this sentence:

> The first question you need to ask yourself is whether the fulfillment of your dream project is worth quitting your 9-to-5 job. Consider what repercussions this will have, if you feel ready to take up a new challenge and whether you have the financial means to start your **entrepreneurship**.

Is this last word used correctly here? I thought it was only used to describe a certain skill, and online dictionaries (like Cambridge) seem to confirm it. Wouldn't for example "business" be more suitable here?

Comment: is worth quitting your x job **for**. financial means to be an entrepreneur. Forget the ship.

Answer (score 2):

Entrepreneurship is a 'buzzword' used to make the whole venture sound more exciting.

From the built-in Apple dictionary…

> the activity of setting up a business or businesses, taking on financial risks in the hope of profit: *the new business opportunities have encouraged entrepreneurship on a grand scale.*

'Business' would be a sensible synonym… just less 'go-getting'. It depends whether you're trying to sell an idea, or just describe a situation.

…and from the same dictionary - buzzword

> a word or phrase, often an item of jargon, that is fashionable at a particular time or in a particular context: *the latest buzzword in international travel is ‘ecotourism’.*

Answer (score -1):

"Entrepreneurship" is not a synonym for "business".

In this sentence "entrepreneurship" refers to the condition of starting the work towards starting your own business(es).

Long before you actually start your business, you may have to quit your job so you can lay the groundwork for starting the business, like networking, educating yourself, market research, scouting locations, talking to banks, and on and on.

The sentence you've quoted tells you to make sure you're in a good position to start **all this work**, not start the business itself.